# Convert row with columns of data into multiple rows with key value columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a `SELECT` inside a stored procedures which outputs data into this format.

```
          A      B      C
rowkey    1      2      3
```

I need to transform it into something like this:

```
         key  value
rowkey   A    1
rowkey   B    2
rowkey   C    3
```

How should I go about transforming it into this?

I am not allowed to touch the `SELECT` statement, so I should find a way to transform it perhaps creating a temporary table.

Comment: This answer can show you some methods in SQL server:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113251/tsql-help-with-unpivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to get you going if you're in SQL 2005 or higher...

You would store the result of your internal SELECT into a table variable, then transform it with something like the below:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (rowkey int identity, A int, B int, C int)

INSERT INTO @test (A, B, C)
VALUES (1, 2, 3)

SELECT rowkey, [Key], [Value]
FROM
(SELECT rowkey, A, B, C
FROM @test) t
UNPIVOT
( [Value] FOR [Key]  IN
    (A, B, C)
) AS u
```