# SQL reshaping rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following columns :

```
Name, Img1, Img2
```

A snap shot of the data looks like this :

```
Stack, lemon.jpg, null
Stack, null, orange.jpg
Stack,plum.jpg, null
Stack,grape.jpg, aubergine.jpg
```

There is no limit for the number of images associated with each name.

But, I want to return the first ten images like below :

```
select name, img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6 ... img10
```

Comment: Perhaps you should redesign your database schema. Why do you want the data in columns, it seems to be sparsly populated and infinite.

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: See the question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113251/tsql-help-with-unpivot

Comment: how do you order the data in the snap shot? what makes `lemon.jpg, null` come before `null, orange.jpg`?

Comment: @Jodrell the order is not important, can be any order

Comment: @NimChimpsky, so its any 10, not the first 10 and the result is non deterministic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data in your table is denormalized, I would suggest unpivoting the data first, then applying the PIVOT function to convert the values back into the final result that you want.

The first step is to unpivot the `img1` and `img2` columns, into multiple rows:

```
select d.name,
  c.value,
  c.col 
    + cast(row_number() over(partition by d.name 
                             order by d.name) as varchar(10)) new_col
from yourtable d
cross apply
(
  select 'img', img1 union all
  select 'img', img2
) c (col, value);
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce0c3/14). The unpivot process will give you a result:

```
|  NAME |         VALUE | NEW_COL |
-----------------------------------
| Stack |     lemon.jpg |    img1 |
| Stack |        (null) |    img2 |
| Stack |        (null) |    img3 |
| Stack |    orange.jpg |    img4 |
| Stack |      plum.jpg |    img5 |
| Stack |        (null) |    img6 |
| Stack |     grape.jpg |    img7 |
| Stack | aubergine.jpg |    img8 |
```

Then you can apply the pivot function to the values in `new_col`, which was calculated by using `row_number()` partitioned by the name:

```
select name, img1, img2, img3, img4, img5,
  img6, img7, img8, img9, img10
from
(
  select d.name,
    c.value,
    c.col 
      + cast(row_number() over(partition by d.name 
                               order by d.name) as varchar(10)) new_col
  from yourtable d
  cross apply
  (
    select 'img', img1 union all
    select 'img', img2
  ) c (col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for new_col in (img1, img2, img3, img4, img5,
                  img6, img7, img8, img9, img10)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce0c3/13)

Answer (score 1):

how about,

[**Now with working fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce0c3/33)

```
    WITH snapshot(n, name, img1, img2) AS
(
    SELECT TOP 5
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) n,
                name,
                img1,
                img2
        FROM yourtable
        WHERE name = 'Stack'
        ORDER BY Name    
)
SELECT
             row1.Name,
             row1.Img1,
             row1.Img2,
             row2.Img1 Img3,
             row2.Img2 Img4,
             row3.Img1 Img5,
             row3.Img2 Img6,
             row4.Img1 Img7,
             row4.Img2 Img8,
             row5.Img1 Img9,
             row5.Img2 Img10
    FROM snapshot row1
        LEFT JOIN snapshot row2 ON row2.n = 2
        LEFT JOIN snapshot row3 ON row3.n = 3
        LEFT JOIN snapshot row4 ON row4.n = 4
        LEFT JOIN snapshot row5 ON row5.n = 5
    WHERE row1.n = 1
```

---

This works by defining a CTE,

```
    SELECT TOP 5
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Name) n,
                name,
                img1,
                img2
        FROM yourtable
        WHERE name = 'Stack'
        ORDER BY Name
```

The results of which could be

```
N  NAME   IMG1       IMG2 
1  Stack  lemon.jpg  (null) 
2  Stack  (null)     orange.jpg 
3  Stack  plum.jpg   (null) 
4  Stack  grape.jpg  aubergine.jpg
```

It then selects the first row and does a left self join for each subsequent pair that is required.